# getting parsing exception in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

---

This error only occurs when i'm adding to type in query but i need to add the type so please help me. Here is an error i'm getting when i query to ES

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse [multi_match] query type [knowledge]. unknown type."
        }
    ],
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse [multi_match] query type [knowledge]. unknown type."
},
"status": 400}
```

---

my query(elastic search) is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":   "computer",
      "type": "knowledge",
      "fields": ["topic.name","title" ] 
    }
  }
}`
```

i've used "type" and "_type" in query both are not working in my case.

Comment: You need to remove `"type": "knowledge",` and it will work, the type can be specified in the URL

Comment: may i know how ?  my current url is: xyz.com/index/_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type here doesn't has the same meaning as you're thinking it to be. The possible variants for type are best_fields, most_fields, etc. Please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) for more details.

For you specific case, you should make a request like this:

```
GET index_name/your_type/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":   "computer",
      "fields": ["topic.name","title" ] 
    }
  }
}
```